# .Range("...").Find generates Object variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find a keyword and then execute an action on it.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow as Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRow = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="", After:=Range("A10")).Row

NextRow = ws.Range("A:K").Find(What:="This City Is:").Row

ws.Cells(LastRow, 1) = Me.tbTextbox1.Value
ws.Cells(LastRow, 2) = Me.tbTextbox1.Value
ws.Cells(LastRow, 3) = Me.tbTextbox3.Value
ws.Cells(NextRow, 4) = "This City is: " + Me.tbTextbox4.Value

End Sub
```

The part I am having a problem with is NextRow.

```
NextRow = ws.Range("A:K").Find(What:="This City Is:").Row
```

It is saying

> "Object variable or With Block variable not set"

I am trying to have Textbox4 row equal wherever the Text "This City Is:" would be. Because sometimes if I decide to insert a line somewhere, I still want the code to follow this term.

Comment: `NextRow` should be declared as `Long`, not as a `String`

Comment: @DarrellH true, but unlikely the problem here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> NextRow = ws.Range("A:K").Find(What:="This City Is:").Row
> ```

You're assuming that `Range.Find` will find what it's looking for... and it doesn't.

So the `.Row` member call goes against `Nothing`, because `Range.Find` returns `Nothing` when it doesn't find what it's looking for. Any member call made against `Nothing` will raise error 91.

**NEVER** use the return value of `Range.Find` without first validating it. Capture the return value in a `Range` reference:

```
Dim result As Range
Set result = ws.Range("...").Find(...)
```

Then make sure it's not `Nothing`:

```
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    NextRow = result.Row
    ...
End If
```

---

Note that [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (free, open-source VBIDE add-in project that I manage) warns about this (and MANY other) situation:

[image: Result of 'Range.Find' call is not tested for 'Nothing']